# Subclassing in Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, subclass

I have a storage class in Typescript, that implements `Storage` interface, say `MyStorage`. But it has too many methods, so I want to use it instead of `MyStorage.getCandy` - `MyStorage.Candies.getCandies`.
How can the structure possibly look?

I assume, something like

```
export class MyStorage implements Storage {

public constructor {} ...

Candies: {
   getCandies() { ... }
}

Balls: {
...
}
}
```

Comment: You could make `MyStorage` an abstract class. Then create subclasses extending `MyStorage`.  `export class CandiesStorage extends MyStorage`

Comment: Why not a separate interface/class?

Comment: @eddiewould The reason is I want to keep only one instance of storage at the place where it is used, not `candyStorage`, `ballStorage`, `flowersStorage` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider whether such a huge object makes sense. Classes that do everything are generally a bad idea, you should split them up in several classes that each deals with a specific object type (ie one class for Balls, one for Candies etc.) and use those classes. If you want to share code you can put it in a base class (preferably an abstract base class if it has no concrete functionality). A solution might look like this:

```
export abstract class MyStorage implements Storage { 

}
export class CandiesStorage extends MyStorage { 
    getCandies() {}
}

export class BallsStorage extends MyStorage { 
}
```

That being said, if for your own reasons this is not feasible, you can split up the functions like this, you just have the operator wrong, you need to initialize the `Candies` field with `=` not with `:` (`:` is a type annotation not field initialization inside a class). One problem with this approach is that inside the object literal functions (for example `getCandies`), `this` will refer to the object literal if you use regular functions. The simplest solution would be to use an arrow function or to add an extra `owner` field to allow access to the containing class instance. Here is a solution that exemplifies both options:

```
export class MyStorage implements Storage {

    public constructor (){ }

    Candies = {
        getCandies: () => {
            this.Balls // this refers to MyStorage
        }
    }

    Balls = { 
        owner: this, // capture the owner object in a field
        getBalls() {
            this.owner.Candies // this refers to the Balls objects, but we can use owner to access the container
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you annotate the type of `owner`?

Answer (score 2):

You could make `MyStorage` and abstract class.  Inside `MyStorage` you could have functionality that will be used/shared across all subclasses my `MyStorage`.  Then create concrete classes that extend `MyStorage` which will contain specific functionality to that subclass.

Storage interface

```
export interface Storage {
    ...abstract interface methods.
}
```

Abstract storage class

```
export abstract class MyStorage implements Storage {
    ...shared functionality between subclasses of MyStorage
}
```

Concrete implementations

```
export class CandiesStorage extends MyStorage {
    ...your Candies specific functionality.
}

export class BallStorage extends MyStorage {
    ...your Ball specific functionality.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant.  MyStorage is a class,  but getCandies is a instance methods not static 。