# Namespaces or categories in TypeScript class

Tags: typescript

I have a base class with methods that access different kind of objects:

```
- findPropertyAInItemY(items)
- getPropertyBInItemZ()
- getItemY()
- getAlltems()
```

they sometimes access private class variables, sometimes not. The methods have sometimes parameter, sometimes not. There are different cases...

These method names become very long but they describe exactly what they return. But there a lot of methods. Therefor I would like to have a structure like:

```
- Properties.getPropertyA()
- Properties.findPropertyB()
- Items.getItemY()
- Item.getAllItems()
```

in my base class. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930410/subclassing-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a hundred percent certain what you want to achieve, but you can get what you're asking in several ways. Although the `static` version looks exactly like what you are asking for, it is usually better to accept an instance in your constructor of a class that will satisfy the dependency (but that's expanding the question a fair bit).

```
class Properties {
  getPropertyA() {

  }

  findPropertyB() {

  }

  static getPropertyC() {

  }
}

class Example {
  private properties = new Properties();

  example() {
    this.properties.getPropertyA();
  }

  example2() {
    Properties.getPropertyC();
  }
}
```